# scanning string in c++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int test;
  cin>>test;
  for(int i=0;i<test;i++){
   string name;
 
   getline(cin,name);
   cout<<name<<"\n";
  }

}
```

input
2
Pratik Patil
Niranjan shirdhone

output:
Pratik Patil

why this code not scanning string for second test case?

Comment: [Why should I not include bits/stdc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @RohanBari check again please.  I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `std::cin >> test` syntax, a newline is always appended at the end as soon as <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. The leading newline inhibits the expected functionality of your program, it follows that it must be skipped or ignored somehow.

That's why `std::getline()` ignores the input. You need to discard that newline character. A simple solution to that is to call `std::cin.ignore()` after the the first extraction:

```
cin >> test;
cin.ignore();
...
```

Comment: Thanks . Now it's giving correct output .